# Understanding solution to finding optimal strategy for game involving picking pots of gold

Tags: algorithm

I am having trouble understanding the reasoning behind the solution to [this question on CareerCup](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=15422849).

> Pots of gold game: Two players A & B. There are pots of gold arranged
>   in a line, each containing some gold coins (the players can see how
>   many coins are there in each gold pot - perfect information). They get
>   alternating turns in which the player can pick a pot from one of the
>   ends of the line. The winner is the player which has a higher number
>   of coins at the end. The objective is to "maximize" the number of
>   coins collected by A, assuming B also plays optimally. A starts the
>   game.
>
> The idea is to find an optimal strategy that makes A win knowing that
>   B is playing optimally as well. How would you do that?
>
> At the end I was asked to code this strategy!

This was a question from a Google interview.

The proposed solution is:

```
function max_coin( int *coin, int start, int end ):
    if start > end:
        return 0

    // I DON'T UNDERSTAND THESE NEXT TWO LINES
    int a = coin[start] + min(max_coin(coin, start+2, end), max_coin(coin, start+1, end-1))
    int b = coin[end] + min(max_coin(coin, start+1,end-1), max_coin(coin, start, end-2))

    return max(a,b)
```

There are two specific sections I don't understand:

1. In the first line why do we use the ranges [start + 2, end] and [start + 1, end - 1]? It's always leaving out one coin jar. Shouldn't it be [start + 1, end] because we took the starting coin jar out?
2. In the first line, why do we take the minimum of the two results and not the maximum?
3. Because I'm confused about why the two lines take the minimum and why we choose those specific ranges, I'm not really sure what `a` and `b` actually represent?

Comment: Are you sure that is java?

Comment: You have to recursively solve each subtask .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a` and `b` here represent the maximum `A` can get by picking the starting pot or the ending pot, respectively.

We're actually trying to maximize `A-B`, but since `B = TotalGold - A`, we're trying to maximize `2A - TotalGold`, and since `TotalGold` is constant, we're trying to maximize `2A`, which is the same as `A`, so we completely ignore the values of `B`'s picks and just work with `A`.

The updated parameters in the recursive calls include `B` picking as well - so `coin[start]` represents `A` picking the start, then `B` picks the next one from the start, so it's `start+2`. For the next call, `B` picks from the end, so it's `start+1` and `end-1`. Similarly for the rest.

We're taking the `min`, because `B` will try to maximize it's own profit, so it will pick the choice that minimizes `A`'s profit.

But actually I'd say this solution is lacking a bit in the sense that it just returns a single value, not 'an optimal strategy', which, in my mind, would be a sequence of moves. And it also doesn't take into account the possibility that `A` can't win, in which case one might want to output a message saying that it's not possible, but this would really be something to clarify with the interviewer.

Answer (score 15):

First of all `a` and `b` represent respectively the maximum gain if `start` (respectively `end`) is played.

So let explain this line:

```
int a = coin[start] + min(max_coin(coin, start+2, end), max_coin(coin, start+1, end-1))
```

If I play `start`, I will immediately gain `coin[start]`. The other player now has to play between `start+1` and `end`. He plays to maximize his gain. However since the number of coin is fixed, this amounts to minimize mine. Note that

- if he plays `start+1` I'll gain `max_coin(coin, start+2, end)`
- if he plays `end` Ill gain `max_coin(coin, start+1, end-1)`

Since he tries to minimize my gain, I'll gain the minimum of those two.

Same reasoning apply to the other line where I play `end`.

**Note:** This is a bad recursive implementation. First of all `max_coin(coin, start+1, end-1)` is computed twice. Even if you fix that, you'll end up computing lots of time shorter case. This is very similar to what happens if you try to compute Fibonacci numbers using recursion. It would be better to use memoization or dynamic programming.

Comment: can you please explain how to solve above problem using dynamic programming.

Comment: @coder_15 you just store the intermediate values in a table or something similar to avoid recomputing them.

Comment: plus 1 for better explanation

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer your points in reverse order, somehow it seems to make more sense that way.

3 - a and b represent the amount of coins the first player will get, when he/she chooses the first or the last pot respectively

2 - we take the minimum because it is the choice of the second player - he/she will act to minimise the amount of coins the first player will get

1 -  the first line presents the scenario - if the first player has taken the first pot, what will the second player do?  If he/she again takes the first pot, it will leave (start+2, end).  If he/she takes the last pot, it will leave (start+1, end-1)

Answer (score 1):

Assume what you gain on your turn is `x` and what you get in all consequent turns is `y`. Both values represent `x+y`, where `a` assumes you take next pot (`x=coin[start]`) from the front and `b` assumes you take your next pot (`x=coin[end]`) from the back.

Now how you compute `y`.

After your choice, the opponent will use the same optimum strategy (thus recursive calls) to maximise his profit, and you will be left with a the smaller profit for the turn. This is why your `y=min(best_strategy_front(), best_strategy_end())` -- your value is the smaller of the two choices that are left because the opponent will take the bigger.

The indexing simply indicates the remaining sequences minus one pot on the front and on the back after you made your choice.

Answer (score 0):

A penny from my end too. I have explained steps in detail.

```
public class Problem08 {
  static int dp[][];

  public static int optimalGameStrategy(int arr[], int i, int j) {
    //If one single element then choose that.
    if(i == j) return arr[i];

    //If only two elements then choose the max.
    if (i + 1 == j ) return Math.max(arr[i], arr[j]);

    //If the result is already computed, then return that.
    if(dp[i][j] != -1) return dp[i][j];

    /**
     * If I choose i, then the array length will shrink to i+1 to j.
     * The next move is of the opponent. And whatever he choose, I would want the result to be
     * minimum. If he choose j, then array will shrink to i+1, j-1. But if also choose i then
     * array will shrink to i+2,j. Whatever he choose, I want the result to be min, hence I take
     * the minimum of his two choices.
     *
     * Similarly for a case, when I choose j.
     *
     * I will eventually take the maximum of both of my case. :)
     */
    int iChooseI = arr[i] + Math.min(optimalGameStrategy(arr, i+1, j-1),
        optimalGameStrategy(arr, i+2, j));
    int iChooseJ = arr[j] + Math.min(optimalGameStrategy(arr, i+1, j-1),
        optimalGameStrategy(arr, i, j-2));
    int res = Math.max(iChooseI, iChooseJ );
    dp[i][j] = res;
    return res;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[]{5,3,7,10};
    dp = new int[arr.length][arr.length];
    for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for(int j=0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        dp[i][j] = -1;
      }
    }
    System.out.println( " Nas: " + optimalGameStrategy(arr, 0, arr.length-1));
  }
}
```